# Benefit of using multiple goroutines

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I've seen code that waits for a group of goroutines to finish:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(2)
go func() {
    // Do work.
    wg.Done()
}()
go func() {
    // Do some other work.
    wg.Done()
}()
wg.Wait()
```

What is the main benefit in doing that, rather than let's say:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(1)
go func() {
    // Do work.
    // Do some more work here instead.
    wg.Done()
}()
wg.Wait()
```

Is it faster?

Comment: Both examples use a single wait group.  What's different is that in the first example, the two tasks run concurrently, whereas in the second task, they run in series. Which is correct or "beneficial", depends, obviously, on the nature of the work being done.

Comment: The second example uses no concurrency; you could remove the `WaitGroup` and the `go` and it would run the same.

Comment: @Adrian thanks - so if i wanted to split out the 'workload' if i had three functions to perform, would I use three goroutines and change to `wg.Add(3)` .. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things to clear: both your examples use a single [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup), the main difference is the "distribution" of work to [goroutines](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements).

In your first example you have 2 concurrent goroutines doing 2 different works (tasks), while in the 2nd example you have 1 single goroutine doing both tasks sequentially, one after the other.

The main benefit *may be* that the 2 goroutines may be scheduled to run in 2 OS threads, which may utilize 2 separate CPU cores, so it may complete earlier / sooner. Whether it does complete earlier and by how much depends on the actual tasks.

The 2 tasks may even *depend* on each other, so it may be that if you put them on a single goroutine they will never complete.